# Sql retrieve results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below order table,i want to retrieve records those are not  in order status "processed" and cacel)status "cancelled" by today date and time(17:00 USA).Please help me to complete my issue.

```
order id  ordername order_status  cancel_status  order_time           cancel_time 
==============================================================================================    
1         Iphone    processed     cancelled      10/08/2012 16:00:00  10/08/2012 16:00:00        
2         samsung   notprocessed  null           null                 null        
3         nokia     processed     cancelled      10/08/2012 16:00:00  10/08/2012 17:00:00    
4         motorola  notprocessed  null           null         null    
5         HTC       processed     null           10/08/2012 17:00:00  null
```

I tried below way but not returning any records.Please help me.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    order 
WHERE 
    to_char(order_time,'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS')>To_char(sysdate,YYYYMMDD) || ' '|| '17:00:00' 
and to_char(cancel_time,'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS')>To_char(sysdate,YYYYMMDD) || ' '|| '17:00:00' 
and order_time is null 
and cancel_time is null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select * from order 
where 
( to_char(order_time,'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS')>To_char(sysdate,YYYYMMDD) || ' '|| '17:00:00' 
or order_time is null ) 
and ( to_char(cancel_time,'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS')>To_char(sysdate,YYYYMMDD) || ' '|| '17:00:00' 
or cancel_time is null )
```

Comment: I should not include orders those are in status of processed and cancelled.in your above querry.there is a chance it will include proceesed, not cancelled or cancelled,not proccessed orders

Comment: Is it lessthan? to_char(order_time,'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS')<To_char(sysdate,YYYYMMDD) || ' '|| '17:00:00'  ?

Comment: frankly i am having great difficulty with translation of the english... sorry.  the main idea is to group your logic with parenthesis and not string it all together with AND

Comment: yes Randy,I understand it,When i compare with time do i need lessthan or greater than?

Comment: less than to get entries earlier in the day, greater than to get entries later (after 5)  not sure what you want.

Comment: I need records today till 5 pm but those are not processed and cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from order o 
where o.order_status != 'processed' 
  and o.cancel_status = 'cancelled' 
  and o.order_time < (trunc(sysdate) + 17/24) 
  and o.cancel_time < (trunc(sysdate) + 17/24)
```

Comment: :Why you are including cancel_status='Cancelled'.I dont want these records.